# Create Event, but table shows null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote an sql event that is supposed to add values to a table, but it returns null values when it isn't supposed to. It is supposed to add times to the finish table

```
USE project;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Finish (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    message VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME NOT NULL
);

SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = OFF;

SHOW PROCESSLIST;



CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS event_1
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
  INSERT INTO Finish(message,created_at)
  VALUES('Delivery Successed',NOW());

SHOW PROCESSLIST;

CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS event_2
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 second
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
-- ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
  INSERT INTO Finish(message,created_at)
  VALUES('Delivery Filed',NOW());
 -- DROP;
 DROP EVENT event_2;
```

Comment: I've checked the first event. It's working fine. By the way, why are you setting event_scheduler `OFF` right after setting it `ON`?

Comment: The finish table should two records, but I don't get the correct table

Comment: How many records do your `finish` table have?

Comment: It supposed to have 2

Comment: Try the full code in your question excluding this line `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = OFF;`

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110868/discussion-between-1000111-and-ashley).

Answer (score 0):

Please give it a try:
(I've removed unnecessary codes;)

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Finish;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Finish (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    message VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME NOT NULL
);



DROP EVENT IF  EXISTS event_1;

CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS event_1
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
  INSERT INTO Finish(message,created_at)
  VALUES('Delivery Successed',NOW());


DROP EVENT IF EXISTS event_2;

CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS event_2
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 second
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
-- ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
  INSERT INTO Finish(message,created_at)
  VALUES('Delivery Filed',NOW());
```

Finally check if `Finish` table is being updated properly.

`SELECT * FROM Finish;`

**Note:** You were setting `event_scheduler` `OFF` right after setting it `ON`. So your newly created events didn't get chance to run.

**More:** `event_1` is a one time event. `event_2` executes in every 5 seconds interval up to one minute from its start time.